# Gnome Shell Lock Screen problem in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: gnome, lock-screen

There is no option for lock Screen. Whenever I switch on from suspend mode, It doesn't show any lock screen.

Comment: This explains the situation "http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86221/how-can-i-lock-my-screen-in-gnome-3-8-without-gdm"

Answer (score 4):

Click the gear icon on the panel, or user name and find System Settings, you can also find it with search.

1. Go to System settings
2. Choose Brightness and lock
3. Then:

   - Set "Lock" option to "ON"
   - Check the box in "Required my password when waking from suspend"
   - Set the time in "Lock screen after:"

Additional option since the above is not working for you.

Open Terminal

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen 'false'
```

This worked on 12.10, not sure about 14.04 but I think it should be the same.

Comment: Its not showing any option for "Brightness and lock" settings In my system setting.

Comment: Check the last line of my original answer for new code to try.

Comment: Also, see if you can manually lock the screen with Ctrl-Alt-l (L lowercase) If not, you may have deleted your screensaver and may need to re-install.

Comment: No, Ctrl-Alt-l  is also not working and I tried to install gnome screen saver it says "gnome-screensaver is already the newest version."

Comment: +1. I can confirm that it is working for Ubuntu Gnome 14.04.

Comment: Try Windows Key + L. It works for me.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem on fresh Kubuntu+ gnome-shell 14.04.1. Unfortunately, RCF-U14.04's answer did not work for me.

Comment: The terminal command worked in Ubuntu Gnome 17.04. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Same problem at first. Then I changed the DM to gdm instead of lightdm, then everything is okay.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
```

Then choose gdm.
Make sure that gdm is installed.
Hope this to be useful.
Good luck!